# Call CloseHandle on handle that is a function parameter?

Tags: c++, winapi

If a handle is created as a function parameter, will it close itself when the  function ends?

eg:

```
int readMem(HANDLE processHandle, int address)
{
    int memValue = 0;

    bool success = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)address, &memValue, sizeToReadBytes, NULL);
    if (!success)
        std::wcout << "Memory read failed on address: " << std::hex << address << "\n";

    return memValue;
}
```

Do I need to explicitly close it before the return statement or is it best to just pass them as references whenever possible?

Or am I just misunderstanding Handles all together? I am quite new to the winapi.

Comment: Are you talking about processHandle?  Don't close it, the caller of this code created it so it "owns" it.  It might use it for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a `HANDLE` is a just a `typedef` to a `void *`.

Microsoft clearly specifies that when you are finished with the handle, be sure to close it using `CloseHandle`.

Your `readMem` function didn't create the handle, therefore it doesn't makes sense to close it there.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to close handle explicitly.

Handle should be closed when its resource is not used, explicitly or implicitly, and not needed anymore. It is not required to close handle as soon as possible. It's up to you to decide when handle is closed. For example, to keep file locked, you have to keep its handle open.

If you forget to close handle, you get resource leak. To ensure that handle is always closed, use RAII approach: create class that accepts `HANDLE` as parameter, doesn't allow to change handle anymore and calls `CloseHandle` in destructor. Wrap handle with this class as soon as you acquire this handle and keep RAII wrapper instance until you don't need it.

If you use RAII and want to acquire handle in one routine and close in another, you want to apply concept of ownership. You can transfer responsibility of closing handle from one routine to another with help of smart pointers `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`. Again, it's safe approach: smart pointers release resource automatically.

Comment: This does not answer the question: **When** should a `HANDLE` be closed.

Comment: @IInspectable - it sort of answers the question (note C++ tag)   use RAII - then it closes when the RAII instance goes out of scope

Comment: @Mark: It doesn't. It merely offloads the responsibility to someone else, and doesn't address the core issue. This immediately leads to a follow-up question: When should the RAII object go out of scope? Not at all helpful.

Comment: It goes out of  scope in the same scope it was constructed iue the construcor has the responsibility for closing as well

Comment: @Mark: Ok then, now which scope should the RAII object be declared in? Should it ever transfer ownership (this is **really** the question that was asked)? Whichever way you put it, this answer does not address the question at all. The edit doesn't help much either: An open file handle does not imply file locking, for example. And writing a `HANDLE`-wrapper is harder than you'd think (different APIs have different ranges for valid `HANDLE` values).

Answer (score 0):

A `HANDLE` is just a pointer. If you called an API function to get some handle value, you need to properly release it before you lose the handle. Likewise, if you copy `HANDLE`s around, you don't need to do anything because they're just a pointer to a resource.

Imagine `HANDLE` being `void*` (which might be the actual type). If you had to do something to the `void*`, you should do it to the handle.