# Edited code using ReadProcessMemory has issues

Tags: c++, winapi

asked a question [Call CloseHandle on handle that is a function parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817833/call-closehandle-on-handle-that-is-a-function-parameter/35817998#35817998)

After someone edited the code, I updated it to find the code no longer works as intended.

> ```
> intptr_t readMem(HANDLE processHandle, intptr_t address, int sizeToReadBytes)
> {
>   intptr_t memValue = 0;
>
>   bool success = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)address, memValue, sizeToReadBytes, NULL);
>   if (!success)
>       std::wcout << "Memory read failed on address: " << std::hex << address << "\n";
>
>   return memValue;
> }
> ```

In the line

```
ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)address, memValue, sizeToReadBytes, NULL);
```

The `memValue` wouldn't compile without `(LPVOID)` or `(LPCVOID)` casts, but with them the code no longer reads the memory (or writes in the case of the functions using `WriteProcessMemory`

Originally (and now I've changed it back in my little program) it uses a reference `&memValue` and works fine.

My question is:

Should this work?
Or is the edit correct and the rest of my program potentially wrong?

I can provide more code if needed, just not sure which bits and didn't want to clog up the screen more than I have... Also should I rollback the edit?

Comment: wrote: or '(LPCVOID)' when it's only '(LPVOID)' for this... That was in the 'WriteProcessMemory' functions...

Comment: *"and the rest of my program potentially wrong?"* - if you have to ask, the answer is usually: Yeah, probably. You are using an API that is way over your head. If casting is challenging, then you should not be reading memory in a running process. Try to write a minesweeper game, and see how that works out. You can come back to cheating later. It's usually harder than learning to play. Plan to invest 5 years, if that is your ultimate goal.

Comment: No, the code was wrong in your last question too

Comment: Your original code (from the first revision, where you use `&memValue`) could only successfully read an integer, i.e., will only work if `sizeToReadBytes` is `4`.  If that's what you meant to do, then keep the `&memValue` but get rid of the `sizeToReadBytes` argument.  If that's not what you meant to do, see Remy's answer.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm getting the idea that misuse of 'intptr_t' is the big problem here, I was using it as something that could store the value of an address as well as the value the address holds. The idea behind 'sizeToReadBytes' was in case I wanted to reuse the code for reading types of varying sizes, like a longlong or something.

Comment: @IInspectable I have no interest in cheating and do plan to invest time learning to code, thanks.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Realising just how bad I am at explaining things (not helped by how horribly slow I am) Just wanted to say thanks for understanding my nonsense... I'll just make it a template and use sizeof instead of the 'sizetoread' ... My own stupidity astounds me sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of `ReadProcessMemory()` is a memory address in the calling process where the function writes the read data to.  You are not passing a memory address, though.  In the code shown in the third revision to the original question, you were type-casting the **value** of an uninitialized integer variable into a memory pointer.  So the function would try to write to random memory. Now you have removed the type-cast, so the code should not even compile anymore.

Your `readMem()` function is not designed correctly. You need to change it so that either:

1. The caller allocates memory of the required size and then the function simply fills the memory:

   ```
   bool readMem(HANDLE processHandle, intptr_t address, void *memValue, int sizeToReadBytes)
   {
     bool success = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)address, memValue, sizeToReadBytes, NULL);
     if (!success)
       std::wcout << "Memory read failed on address: " << std::hex << address << "\n";
     return success;
   }
   ```

   ```
   intptr_t memValue = 0;
   readMem(processHandle, address, &memValue, sizeof(memValue));
   ```
2. The function allocates memory and returns it to the caller:

   ```
   void* readMem(HANDLE processHandle, intptr_t address, int sizeToReadBytes)
   {
     uint8_t memValue = new uint8_t[sizeToReadBytes];
     bool success = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)address, memValue, sizeToReadBytes, NULL);
     if (!success) {
       std::wcout << "Memory read failed on address: " << std::hex << address << "\n";
       delete [] memValue;
       memValue = NULL;
     }
     return memValue;
   }
   ```

   ```
   intptr_t *memValue = (intptr_t*) readMem(processHandle, address, sizeof(intptr_t));
   ...
   delete [] memValue;
   ```

   Or:

   ```
   bool readMem(HANDLE processHandle, intptr_t address, int sizeToReadBytes, std:vector<uint8_t> &memValue)
   {
     memValue.resize(sizeToReadBytes);
     bool success = ReadProcessMemory(processHandle, (LPVOID)address, &memValue[0], sizeToReadBytes, NULL);
     if (!success)
       std::wcout << "Memory read failed on address: " << std::hex << address << "\n";
     return success;
   }
   ```

   ```
   std::vector<uint8_t> buffer;
   readMem(processHandle, address, sizeof(intptr_t), buffer);
   intptr_t memValue = (intptr_t*) &buffer[0];
   ```

Comment: I suspect that the function was actually intended to return the integer value at the specified address.  Which makes the `sizeToReadBytes` argument rather pointless, but would explain why the OP thought the function was working (as shown in the first revision). :-)